# Static files not getting generated magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

I ran command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f and i am getting this error https://prnt.sc/ot0gpp
Please help what to do, my static files are not getting generated because of which my site is down. its very urgent, please help

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in less/css

You can run static content deploy with errors on to get more of an idea on what is wrong. However you will have to work through the errors fixing them as you seem them. Typically it's missing less variables.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 -d display_errors=1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If you are really not sure what the errors refer to I suggest hiring a developer to take a look to fix your site.